# When would I want to set a stride in the batch or channel dimension for TensorFlow convolution?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, stride

Tensor flow implements a basic convolution operation with [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d).

I am specifically interested in the "strides" parameter, which lets you set the stride of the convolution filter -- how far across the image you shift the filter each time.

The example given in [one of the early tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros), with an image stride of 1 in each direction, is

```
def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

The strides array is explained more in the linked docs:

> In detail, with the default NHWC format...
>
> Must have strides[0] = strides[3] = 1. For the most common case of the same horizontal and vertices strides, strides = [1, stride, stride, 1].

Note the order of "strides" matches the order of inputs: `[batch, height, width, channels]` in the NHWC format.

Obviously having a stride of not 1 for `batch` and `channels` wouldn't make sense, right? (your filter should always go across every batch and every channel)

But why is it even an option to put something other than 1 in `strides[0]` and `strides[3]`, then? (where it being an "option" is in regards to the fact that you could put something other than 1 in the python array you pass in, disregarding the documentation quote above)

Is there a situation where I would have a non-one stride for the `batch` or `channels` dimension, e.g.

```
tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[2, 1, 1, 2], padding='SAME')
```

If so, what would that example even mean in terms of the convolution operation?

Answer (score -1):

There might be a situation where you send a video in chunks. That means your batch will be a sequence of frames. And assuming that close frames should be quite similar we can omit some of them by increasing batch stride. That as far as I understand. IDK about channel stride though